# Windows: fixing 'messed up' services and their dependencies

Tags: windows-10, wireless-networking, services

I was trying to fix a problem with my wifi connection last night that involved changing some of the "log ons" for various network-related (I.e. from "Local Service" to "Local System"). Now I'm going to be honest, I shouldn't have messed with these as much as I did, because I'm not entirely versed on what this means, and because now I cannot seem to start a lot of the services important to connecting to the internet. When I try to start them, I get ether error "1068: the dependency service or group failed to start", or" error 1079: the account specified for this service is different from the account specified for other services running in the same process."

What's more, when I try to go to the "dependencies" tab for **any** service, I get an error (the same one as 1079, but as an alert). Therefore I don't even know when the dependencies are for each service that gives me an error.

So I definitely bit off more than I can chew with this, and I'm looking for solutions. First of all, is there a way to 'reset' the account information for all windows services? Otherwise, is there some kind of reference that contains this information?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't feel too bad. You aren't the first one to do that and won't be the last. That is how you learn. Try tweaking,com and their Windows Repair. It can be a beast. If services are your only issue tell it to repair services only and un-check all the others.

http://www.tweaking.com/

Comment: Thanks for the response; I ran the repair for just the services reset, but the network connections service (among others) still won't start. They still give me the same errors. :(

Comment: It was worth a shot. At this point what are the services that won't start? I can give to the default settings......

Comment: Update: I ran Tweaker again with some more options, and was able to get it to a point where all the services started (however I had to set some of their log ons to "local system" even after running it on order to get them to start). So now they're all running, and I can connect to networks, but I can't seem to get internet access (it stalls on 'identifying'.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is a separate problem, or if it has to do with what I set in the service settings.

Comment: When you go in to the services applet sort by starup type. You can then easily scroll through the "automatics" and see which ones didn't start. Unfortunately the login is critical. Did it set them back to what they should have been but you didn't know the passwords?

Comment: Thanks for the help, I've since fixed the problem by finding the registry entry which contained all of the service group info, and then changing their logins to match. I seem to have fixed all the dependencies.